# How to disable all yesterday's date from date picker

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker

I want to know how can I disable all the yesterday dates when a user requests a date picker. For example when date picker is opened it should allow users to select a date that starts from today and ends after two days.

Like if current date is 22-03-2020 all its previous dates should be disabled and all its future dates should also be disabled from 24-03-2020 and this loop should repeat everytime.

This is worrying me as my app is about to release in a week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000;
dp_time.getDatePicker().setMinDate(now);
dp_time.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(now+(1000*60*60*24*7)); //After 7 Days from Now for example
```

Answer (score 1):

Set min date on the datepicker, applying a minus of 1 second:

```
datePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() -1000);
```